# While running the first HIPI program, I am getting error of JSON. Where should I add it and how?

Tags: java, json, hadoop, hipi

Input FS:

```
local FS
```

Output HIB:

```
sampleimages.hib
Overwrite HIB if it exists: true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/JSONValue
at org.hipi.image.HipiImageHeader.getMetaDataAsBytes(HipiImageHeader.java:296) 
at org.hipi.image.HipiImageHeader.write(HipiImageHeader.java:393)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, so I made the hipi jar by myself by integrating necessary packages. If you want, you can integrate the packages and create jar file yourself for the missing packages. If you don't want to, and build with a pre-built jar:

[Pre-built HIPI jar](https://github.com/ishitvyas/hadoop-hipi-prebuilt-jar/blob/master/hipi-2.1.0.jar)

1. Download the JAR
2. Replace the jar file in hipi/core/build/libs
3. Build Gradle from core directory
4. Build Gradle from hipi root directory